# How to translated URL endpoint in Laravel php?

Tags: endpoint, laravel-9, laravel-translatable

In Laravel, how can I accomplish url endpoint translation?

I want to translate my endpoint using the language that I have chosen in Ruby on Rails. Is it possible to accomplish this?
For instance, when I translate or switch languages in - Englist -> DomainName.com/home, let's say I have the language French -> DomainName.com/maison.

I'm trying to define two different URLs in both languages to do this, but I'd like to discover the most efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by -

1. **Create Language Files:**
   Create language files for each language you want to support in the `resources/lang` directory. For example, you might have `routes.php` files for English and French:

   ```
   lang/
       ├── en/
       │   └── routes.php
       └── fr/
           └── routes.php
   ```

   ```php
   // lang/en/routes.php
   return [
       'home' => 'home',
   ];
   ```

   ```php
   // lang/fr/routes.php
   return [
       'home' => 'maison',
   ];
   ```
2. **Create a Helper to Translate Routes:**
   Define a helper function to translate route names in your application. Create a helper file (e.g., `Helpers.php`) if you don't have one, and add the following function:

   ```php
   // app/Helpers.php
   if (!function_exists('langRoute')) {
       function langRoute($value)
       {
           return trans("routes.$value");
       }
   }
   ```

   Make sure to autoload this file in your `composer.json`:

   ```json
   "autoload": {
       "files": [
           "app/Helpers.php"
       ]
   }
   ```

   Then run `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloader.
3. **Define Route with Translated Name:**
   In your `web.php` routes file, use the `langRoute` helper to define routes with translated names:

   ```php
   // routes/web.php
   use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

   Route::get(langRoute('home'), [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
   ```
4. **Generate Translated URLs:**
   In your Blade views, use the `route` function with the translated route name to generate URLs dynamically:

   ```html
   <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a>
   ```
5. **Set Locale in Middleware:**
   Create a middleware to set the application locale based on user preferences or the language specified in the URL:

   ```php
       app()->setLocale($userLocale);
   ```